# Junit tests for Message hashing with Sha2

Tags: java, junit, sha

How can I test this message Hashing function? In fact, I am seeking for some tests using some Strings that will fail this method, I've got for now a test for a NoSuchAlgorithmException  and a NullExeption .. thank's in advance :)

```
public String HashMessage(String message){

MessageDigest messageDigest messageDigest=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    messageDigest.update(message.getBytes());

    byte byteData[] = messageDigest.digest();

    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i=0;i<byteData.length;i++) {
        String hex=Integer.toHexString(mask & byteData[i]);
        if(hex.length()==1)
            hexString.append('0');
        hexString.append(hex);
    }
    return hexString.toString();

}
```

Comment: Your hexstringification is odd (and reverse from what I'd expect). Testing cryptocraphic functions is usually done via test vectors: http://www.di-mgt.com.au/sha_testvectors.html

Comment: okay, thank's those test vectors are helpful, do you have some other tests that can fail this method ?